# bcrypt encryption to encrypt passwords in txt file

Tags: python, encryption, bcrypt

I am geting an error when trying to check a password using the bcrypt library. The issue seems to be that the **hashed**  variable should be a plain string without "quotation marks". I've attempted to remove the quotation marks multiple times but the error persists. I am seeking assistance in removing the quotation marks from the "hashed" variable in order to make the bcrypt `checkpw` function work properly.

```python
#----------------------------------------------------------------
#----------------------------------------------------------------
# import module to dencrypt password
#----------------------------------------------------------------
#----------------------------------------------------------------

import bcrypt
       
def Log_in():
    # Print separator line
    print("-"*70)

    # Prompt user for email or username and password
    msg0 = "Enter your username or your email address"
    msg1 = "Enter your password"
    user_input = input(f"{msg0:45}| ")
    user_pasword = input(f"{msg1:45}| ")
    print("-"*70)
        
    # Open and read the text file where the user database is stored
    db = open("database.txt",'r') 
    contant = db.readlines()
    email_list = []
    username_list = []
    password_list=[]    

    # Check if there's content in the database
    if contant == None:
        pass
    else:    
        # Split each line of the content by '| ' and append the parts to their corresponding lists
        for i in contant:
            a, b, c, d = i.split("| ")
            email_list.append(a.strip())
            username_list.append(b.strip())
            password_list.append(d.strip())
              
    # Close the file         
    db.close()
       
    # Check if the entered email or username exists in the email_list or username_list
    if user_input in username_list or user_input in email_list:
        x = None
        y = None

        # Try to get the index of the entered email or username in the email_list and username_list    
        try:
            x = username_list.index(user_input)
        except:
            pass
        try:
            y = email_list.index(user_input)
        except:
            pass
            
                 
        if x != None and y == None:
            # If the entered username exists in the username_list
            # Strip the 'b' character, encode the string to utf-8 and compare it with the entered password                
            hashed = password_list[x].strip('b')
            # hashed = hashed.replace("'","")
            hashed = hashed.encode('utf-8')
            if bcrypt.checkpw(user_pasword.encode('utf-8'), hashed):
                print("Welcome")
            else:
                print("incorrect password")
    
                Log_in()
            
        elif y != None or x == None:
            # If the entered email exists in the email_list
            # Remove the double quotes and compare it with the entered password
            hashed = password_list[y][:-1]
            hashed = hashed.replace('"','')
            # hashed1 = hashed.replace(b"\n", b"")
                
            if bcrypt.checkpw((user_pasword.encode("utf-8")),hashed): #error happening here
                print("Welcome")
            else:
                print("incorrect password")
                Log_in()
                    
        else:
            print("incorrect password")
            Log_in()       
    else:
        # If the entered email or username doesn't exist in the email_list or username_list
            print("This username or the email does not exist")
        Log_in()
             
                
# main function                
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Log_in()
```

Comment: This code could be cleaned up and simplified substantially, but I'm not sure what your problem is anyway. From these lines `hashed = password_list[x].strip('b'); hashed = hashed.encode('utf-8')` I'm guessing you've stored the bytes string that `bcrypt.checkpw()` produces using the `print()` function. Well, don't do that, instead decode it into a string first. But if you do read in b'abcd' from your file then just remove the leading `b'` and the trailing `'`.

Comment: I removed ```b```, but it still doesn't work. I got the encoded password from '''txt file manually'''. and it works normally. I still don't know what I can do to solve this problem. @PresidentJamesK.Polk